# sorting fractions when denominator is a fraction itself

Tags: python, fractions

Few minutes ago I've asked a question about sorting dictionary where keys are fractions (simple fractions).

I know now that I have to use fractions module but the module doesn't work when a denominator of a fraction is a fraction itself.

e.g.

"1/1.6", 1/2.5"

```
>>> import fractions
>>> f = '1/1.6'
>>> fractions.Fraction(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fractions.py", line 125, in __new__
    numerator)
ValueError: Invalid literal for Fraction: '1/1.6'
```

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 6):

Python's `fractions` module is designed to work with exact rationals (whether Fraction, Decimal, or otherwise), not approximate floats. So, they intentionally don't have a constructor that takes a pair of `float`s, or a string fraction made of two floats.

However, they *do* have a constructor that takes a single `float`, or a single string float. If you know that's what you really want, you can do this:

```
>>> f = Fraction('1') / Fraction('1.6')
Fraction(5, 8)
>>> f = Fraction(1) / Fraction(1.6)
Fraction(2251799813685248, 3602879701896397)
```

You'll probably notice that `Fraction('1.6')` returns something very different from `Fraction(1.6)`. The former returns the simplest fraction that would be rendered as "1.6"; the latter returns the simplest fraction that matches the inexact float value 1.6.

So:

```
>>> a = ['1/1.6', '1/2.5', '3/4', '1.1/10']
>>> nd = [x.split('/') for x in a]
>>> nd
[['1', '1.6'], ['1', '2.5'], ['3', '4'], ['1.1', '10']]
>>> f = [Fraction(x[0]) / Fraction(x[1]) for x in nd]
>>> f
[Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(2, 5), Fraction(3, 4), Fraction(11, 100)]
>>> sorted(f)
[Fraction(11, 100), Fraction(2, 5), Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(3, 4)]
```

Putting it all together, if you want to sort a list of strings by what their equivalent values as fractions of decimals would be:

```
>>> def fractionize(s):
>>>   n, d = s.split('/')
>>>   return Fraction(n) / Fraction(d)
>>> sorted(a, key=fractionize)
['1.1/10', '1/2.5', '1/1.6', '3/4']
```

Of course if you need to do a lot of this kind of thing, you might want to write your own fraction module (or look at the thousands of online recipes for one that's already written) that can just process '1/1.6' in the way you want, so you don't need the `fractionize` function.

Comment: As it stands, your solution has a side-effect of reducing the fractions in the list, which is not exactly what the OP seeks. I think it would better if it was revised it to show using your technique to sort a list of fractions given in string format to produce a sorted result containing them in the original format.

Comment: Well, as it stands, my solution doesn't have a complete answer at all… But you're right, it's probably worth editing so it answers what the OP is trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can `eval` all elements of your array, like this:

```
a = ["1/1.6","1/2.5","6+7","-1*3"]
sorted(a, key=eval)
```

returns

```
['-1*3', '1/2.5', '1/1.6', '6+7']
```

It might be a bit slow, but it should work.

Note that you'll need `python3` to have fractions like `1/3` work correctly (because in python2 `/` is integer division, not float division.  To fix you could add `'1.0*'` to the start of all of your strings).

Comment: @zalkap: Don't just say "it doesn't work"; give the data that makes it fail, and then he can either explain why it fails or adapt his code so it will work. (In this case, you probably shouldn't be using `eval`—that's generally a last resort at best—but it's still probably worth it for you to understand why it's failing.)

Comment: PS, you don't need Python 3; try `from __future__ import division; eval('2/3')` and see.